# Extending South Africa 90 day visitors visa?

Tags: tourist-visas, south-africa, visa-extensions

I'm a Canadian traveling to South Africa next year to join my partner (also Canadian), who will be studying for the year. I will be working remotely but without a work visa, so I'm planning on leaving the continent to renew the visa about every 90 days. This seems to be a workable (if expensive) strategy based on other responses I have read here, however I have a few questions surrounding this:

1) Is it possible for me to get a new 90 day visa, by reentering on the correct dates from my country of residence, if I have already applied/used a 180 day extension? In other words, if I get an extension and use it and leave at the appropriate date, can I get another 90 day visa upon reentering?

2) If I leave the continent before my 90 day visa period is up, and then return within the same time period (ex. I left after 60 days), will I be granted a new 90 day visa? Or will I still be entered with in this case 30 days remaining? I know this is the norm for reentry after visiting other African countries, but what about leaving the continent and then coming back?

Comment: Have you explored the idea of just applying for a visa to visit your friend for the whole time including working remotely (i. e. not being paid by someone in SA) while doing so?

Comment: I definitely have! But it seems like there aren't a lot of options, to get a long-term visitor visa you have to be a journalist/entertainer, something along those lines. Otherwise to get a work visa you need specific skills, or an invitation from a SA company...

Comment: The same problem exists in many Schengen Countries,   where they are over coutious and neglect the economic benefit that they lose by making things to complicated or impossible. I assume the fear of misuse prevails here.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [Life Partner Visa South Africa](https://www.savisas.com/life-partner-visa-south-africa/) which may be helpful.

Whether a **student** fulfills the **permanent resident** requirement is not clear.

But it does offer a simplified work permit. Since you won't be looking for a work within South Africa, it may be a matter of a  simple **endorsement** to work remotely.

At the bottom of the page is a list of all visa combinations on offer.

---

> **Do I qualify for a life partner visa?**
>   The applicant must cohabit with a South African citizen or **permanent resident** at the time of the application and be able to provide evidence thereof.
>
> The couple must prove that they are in a spousal-type relationship for a minimum of 2 years. This is done by showing that they share financial responsibilities and by providing letters of support for the application from friends and family. The couple must live together at the time of the application.
>
> **For work** – once a suitable position has been found and offered via a contract of employment, Intergate Immigration can apply for an **endorsement** to the life partner visa enabling the life partner to work, This negates the need to apply for a work permit or the requirements such as proving no South African is available to take up the position.

---

**Sources**:

- [Apply For A South African Life Partner Visa | SAvisas.com](https://www.savisas.com/life-partner-visa-south-africa/)